# Requirements to connect Datasource on Tableau Server to MSSQL-server

Tags: sql-server, impersonation, tableau-api

here my problem.
I have an installation of Tableau Server in my customer's environment. He has an ERP based on MSSQL-server. I can connect from Tableau Desktop to the MSSQL without any problem and perform any kind of activity, using user "userA". If I try to publish the datasource/workbook to Tableau Server, it seems that it cannot connect to MSSQL-server.
I tried every type of Authentication (prompt, embedded, impersonation) without succeding.

The connection between Tableau Server and the MSSQL Server is ongoing, port 1433 is ok and there is no firewall between. To prove this statement, on Tableau Server there is a .php script that queries the same MSSQL-Server, same DB, same tables, with the same "userA", and I don't have any problem.

````
```{
    "ts": "2019-07-08T15:02:19.080",
    "pid": 1391,
    "tid": "7f079cc3e280",
    "sev": "warn",
    "req": "-",
    "sess": "-",
    "site": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "k": "excp",
    "v": {
        "class": "sqlserver",
        "dse-type": "UnableToConnect",
        "excp-msg": "There was an unknown connection error to the database. The error message below has additional information, but you might need to ask the database administrator to review the database logs.\n[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87]. \n[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired\n[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.\n",
        "excp-type": "DataSourceException",
        "is-bad-request": false,
        "is-local-configuration-error": false,
        "is-remote-configuration-error": false,
        "msg": "DataSourceException::Throw"
    },
    "ctx": {
        "client-type": "dataserver",
        "procid": "31334",
        "requestID": "XSM@vH4HkW-yeIYtlkehBgAAAAA",
        "sessionid": "B4E47296423F488499A719B19EE40BAE-1:0",
        "tid": "140218824414976",
        "username": "tableauserver"
    }
}```
````

I have read following documentation, but I'm still a newbie:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/impers_requ.htm
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/impers_how.htm

What I am asking is: 
what are the requirements to connect to a MSSQL-SErver from Tableau Server?

- do i have to create the same user also on MSSQL-Server? (I'm not the DBA, so I have to ask this test)
- if the previous answer is "yes", does "tableauuser" on MSSQL-Server (the user that owns the datasource) must be granted with IMPERSONATE privilegespresent also on MSSQL db?

Thank you for your kind help
Davide

Comment: Check the *actual* error message first: `Login timeout expired. A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.` This isn't about impersonation, which is *not* needed unless you want to impersonate the *end users* when connecting to SQL Server

Comment: We discovered that from MSSQL's side there were some kind of policy that blocked the connection from that IP to MSSQL. Furthermore, after using a dedicated port, I discovered the correct format to invoke a connection, that is <server> , <port> for Tableau Desktop (working also with <server>\<istance> , <port>. For Tableau Server, when I published the data souce, I had to "Edit Connection" and use <server>, specifying the port in the field "Port". If you specify the <instance> in the TS connection tab it doesn't work..

Comment: Have you tried this - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm
You need to add trusted IP to tableau server then it will allowed you to connect your data source to MSSQL database server.

Comment: Hi, thank you all. The problem was on the syntax as I explained before. Trusted Authentication is working fine, too.